# Sessions collection too big in a MEAN app. Is it okay to clear the collection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, session, mongoose

I'm making changes to an old MEAN app and just found out that the sessions collection is huge (more than 38 million records). I'm sure the app is storing all the sessions of the bots and crawlers. I'm thinking of clearing the sessions collection so that I can take a backup of the database and free up some space.

I can update you with the version of mongoose, express and node.

Is it okay to clear the sessions collection? Will it make any difference when the crawlers and bots make request even-though if they don't store cookies? It is also fine if the app logs out the users.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's completely fine to clear the session, but I'd like you to know that it might result in logging out all the users which are currently logged instead what you can do is set an expiry on the session, so after a set period of time the session gets destroyed. If you're using Mongoose store on express session you can use the following code:

```
app.use(session({
    store: new MongoStore({
      url: 'mongodb://localhost/test-app',
      ttl: 14 * 24 * 60 * 60 // = 14 days. Default
    })
}));
```

Comment: Thanks! Also I keep getting 'Error setting TTL index on collections sessions'. Is this something related? I tried all the possible solutions on the internet and nothing seems to work.

Comment: try backing up and then delete all docs in sessions collection.